# Page activation failing in AEM 6.3

Tags: replication, aem

I am working in **AEM 6.3** and trying to **activate** some pages but getting the below error. It is trying to create the versions of the page and says "**access denied**" but I am using the **admin** account.

I also observed that when I activate the page for the first time, it doesn't give me this error. But when I modify/edit something on the page and again activate it, it gives me the below error.

> 03.08.2017 16:01:56.988 *INFO* [10.78.76.987 [1501789967900] POST /etc/replication/treeactivation.html HTTP/1.1]
>   com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReplicatorImpl Setting up replication with
>   options: ReplicationOptions{synchronous=false, revision='null',
>   suppressStatusUpdate=false, suppressVersions=false, filter=null,
>   aggregateHandler=null}
>   03.08.2017 16:01:59.769 *ERROR* [10.78.76.987 [1501789967900] POST /etc/replication/treeactivation.html HTTP/1.1]
>   org.apache.jsp.libs.cq.replication.components.treeactivation.POST_jsp$Processor
>   Error during tree activation of
>   /content/mysite/en/latest-news/sub-page
>   com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationException: Unable to create version
>   for /content/mysite/en/latest-news    at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.VersionManagerImpl.preprocess(VersionManagerImpl.java:377)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReplicatorImpl.replicate(ReplicatorImpl.java:627)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.libs.cq.replication.components.treeactivation.POST_jsp$Processor.replicate(POST_jsp.java:306)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.libs.cq.replication.components.treeactivation.POST_jsp$Processor.process(POST_jsp.java:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.libs.cq.replication.components.treeactivation.POST_jsp$Processor.process(POST_jsp.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.libs.cq.replication.components.treeactivation.POST_jsp$Processor.process(POST_jsp.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.libs.cq.replication.components.treeactivation.POST_jsp._jspService(POST_jsp.java:519)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:346)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:491)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:552)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:375)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:190)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:71)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.doFilter(AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.java:436)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter.doFilter(ApiResourceFilter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.rest.assets.impl.AssetContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(AssetContentDispositionFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:367)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHandlingServletHelper.handleFilter(FormsHandlingServletHelper.java:221)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHandlingServletHelper.handleFilter(FormsHandlingServletHelper.java:221)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.internal.servlets.CoreFormHandlingServlet.doFilter(CoreFormHandlingServlet.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker.doFilter(CampaignCopyTracker.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:49)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMException: Unable to create version.    at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.PageManagerImpl.createRevision(PageManagerImpl.java:1457)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.PageManagerImpl.createRevision(PageManagerImpl.java:1329)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.VersionManagerImpl.preprocess(VersionManagerImpl.java:374)
>     ... 122 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   javax.jcr.AccessDeniedException: OakAccess0000: Access denied     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException.asRepositoryException(CommitFailedException.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException.asRepositoryException(CommitFailedException.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.newRepositoryException(SessionDelegate.java:670)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.save(SessionDelegate.java:496)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl$8.performVoid(SessionImpl.java:419)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.performVoid(SessionDelegate.java:274)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:416)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.repository.impl.CRX3SessionImpl.save(CRX3SessionImpl.java:208)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.PageManagerImpl.createRevision(PageManagerImpl.java:1395)
>     ... 124 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException: OakAccess0000:
>   Access denied     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authorization.permission.PermissionValidator.checkPermissions(PermissionValidator.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authorization.permission.PermissionValidator.propertyAdded(PermissionValidator.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.propertyAdded(VisibleValidator.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.propertyAdded(VisibleValidator.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.propertyAdded(VisibleValidator.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.propertyAdded(VisibleValidator.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.propertyAdded(VisibleValidator.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.CompositeEditor.propertyAdded(CompositeEditor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.propertyAdded(EditorDiff.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareProperties(SegmentNodeState.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:515)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:608)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:608)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:608)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:608)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:489)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:608)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.process(EditorDiff.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorHook.processCommit(EditorHook.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.CompositeHook.processCommit(CompositeHook.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeStore$Commit.prepare(SegmentNodeStore.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeStore$Commit.optimisticMerge(SegmentNodeStore.java:634)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeStore$Commit.execute(SegmentNodeStore.java:690)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeStore.merge(SegmentNodeStore.java:334)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.core.MutableRoot.commit(MutableRoot.java:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.commit(SessionDelegate.java:347)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.save(SessionDelegate.java:494)
>     ... 129 common frames omitted

Anyone has any idea how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Strange that you get an Access Denied exception while using the admin account. Could you please go to the `/useradmin` console and check the `admin`s user permission? Does it have full permissions (including `Replicate`) over the repository nodes?

Comment: Yes, admin has full permissions including replication on all the node.

Comment: From the logs, it looks you are not activating certain page, but using Tree Activation feature and it fails on creation the version for page `/content/mysite/en/latest-news`. Is there anything specific about this page? Might admin somehow missing write access, is this page locked or under workflow? Can you activate other pages by just simply using publish button?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the OOTB replication workflow?

If affirmative, then:

1. Check the status of running workflows in the workflow console: http://localhost:your_port/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html. Are there any workflows stuck? If so terminate them.
2. Manually clearing the queue might be a solution. You can achieve this by removing the Sling Jobs with topic =replication agent name. Quickest way to do this is to use CRXDE Lite (http://localhost:your_port/crx/de/index.jsp), and delete the node:

`/var/eventing/jobs/assigned/%INSTANCE-SLING-ID%/%REPLICATION-AGENT-FULL-ID%`

So for example with the default publish agent:

`/var/eventing/jobs/assigned/e23dd09d-83f1-4735-a77c-394df479214c/com.day.cq.replication.job.publish`

4. Did you migrate to 6.3 from an older AEM version? Then maybe your version history is broken: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/RecoveryFromBrokenVersionVistory.html
5. Finally, here is the 6.3 page for troubleshooting the replication: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/deploy/troubleshoot-rep.html

If not, and using some custom process step, check how you retrieve the service user inside the process steps.